# Does sql profiler show you the paramater values that were passed in?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler

I'm using this 3rd party sql tracing application because I have sql server express 2008 installed (just a trial version).

It only shows the sql passed into the server, with the parameters like @p1 and not that actual value of the parameter, which to me is not all that usefull.

Does the built in sql profiler show you the actual values the .net web app is passing in like '2342' or a = 200 ?

Answer (score 4):

yes, it shows the query with the parameters already substituted. When I debug, I usually just copy the SQL from the profiler and paste it into Management Studio and run it.

Answer (score 0):

It can.  When you define a profile template, you can specify which sql "things" you want to see and which columns (information) you want to see for each "thing".  So if you aren't seeing the parameters, you may have to modify the profile template you are using.