# sql profiler for sql express 2008 that shows the query with parameter info

Tags: sql-server-2008, trace, sql-server-profiler

Duplicate of: [Does sql profiler show you the paramater values that were passed in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645876/does-sql-profiler-show-you-the-paramater-values-that-were-passed-in)
(Asked by same user.)

Hi,

I need a sql profiler that will show all the sql (raw sql or sproc) that are called to a database, along with the parameters passed into the queries.

I don't mind a commercial product if it has a trial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is open source project I am using with SQL Server 2008 with great success:
[SqlExpressProfiler](http://code.google.com/p/sqlexpressprofiler/)

[Here is screenshot with parameter values:](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/db50c0a595.png)

Comment: How can I filter show it only shows the events where a sql query is passed to it?

Comment: I have added screenshot to show you that it is possible to see actual parameter values...

Answer (score 2):

You can checl xSQL Profiler at http://www.xsqlsoftware.com/Product/xSQL_Profiler.aspx
It's free for SQL Express.